# Detox not finding View element - Error: Cannot find UI Element

Tags: react-native, detox

I am having issues getting detox to find ANY element that I am trying to make it find. As of yet I am not able to get it to find anything. I have followed the setup instructions but for some reason it dosnt work for me.

I am using the very basic setup as described here https://github.com/wix/detox/blob/master/docs/Introduction.GettingStarted.md but for some reason it dosnt want to work for me.

Component:

```
render() {
    return (
        <View testID="MainView">...</View>
    )
}
```

Test:

```
describe('Example', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await device.reloadReactNative();
  });
  it('should have main view', async () => {
    await expect(element(by.id('MainView'))).toExist();
  });
})
```

Error:

```
Exception with Assertion: {
    "Assertion Criteria" : "assertWithMatcher:isNotNil",
    "Element Matcher" : "(((respondsToSelector(accessibilityIdentifier) && accessibilityID('MainView')) && !(kindOfClass('RCTScrollView'))) || (kindOfClass('UIScrollView') && ((kindOfClass('UIView') || respondsToSelector(accessibilityContainer)) && ancestorThatMatches(((respondsToSelector(accessibilityIdentifier) && accessibilityID('MainView')) && kindOfClass('RCTScrollView'))))))",
    "Recovery Suggestion" : "Check if the element exists in the UI hierarchy printed below. If it exists, adjust the matcher so that it accurately matches element."

}

Error Trace: [
    {
        "Description" : "Interaction cannot continue because the desired element was not found.",
        "Error Domain": "com.google.earlgrey.ElementInteractionErrorDomain",
        "Error Code" : "0",
        "File Name" : "GREYElementInteraction.m",
        "Function Name" : "-[GREYElementInteraction matchedElementsWithTimeout:error:]",
        "Line" : "124"
    }
]
```

I have seen this issue in other posts but it is usually to do with trying to locate an element that does not support testID but from my knowledge a `View` should have support.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does this pass? `await expect(element(by.id('MainView'))).toBeVisible();`